# How to format double as hex?

Tags: c++, format, hex, fmt

How can one format double as hex?

```
double t = 1.123;
fmt::format("{:x}", t);
```

It throws exception "invalid type specifier".

I would like to get string `3ff1f7ced916872b`

Comment: That's an odd use case I don't know if `fmt` supports. Consider using brute-force to `reinterpret_cast` to `uint64_t`.

Comment: @user4581301 I tried, compiler says `error: invalid cast from type 'double' to type 'uint64_t'`

Comment: @user4581301: That would violate the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/12149471). I recommend using [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) instead.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel has the better solution. My pitch requires you to dive into pointers, cast the pointers, and then dereference your way back to values. It's, as Andreas says, illegal, but it's the sort of illegal that will only fail on a particularly strange system.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Failed to build with gcc, standart c++20. `bit_cast is not a member of std`

Comment: @TylerDense: Did you `#include <bit>`, as specified in the linked documentation?

Comment: @TylerDense: Did you compile with `-std=c++20`?

Comment: `double t = 1.123; uint64_t x; memcpy(&x, &t, sizeof x)); fmt::format("{:x}", x);`

Comment: If all else fails there's always `memcpy`. https://godbolt.org/z/9jETPbs3G

Comment: @TylerDense: `std::bit_cast` works with gcc 12.2. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/475b5WrGE)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel is there c++17 way?

Comment: @TylerDense: Yes, I believe the `memcpy` solution mentioned by someone else complies with ISO C++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) to cast `double` into an appropriately sized integer and format that in hexadecimal, e.g. assuming IEEE754 `double`:

```
  double t = 1.123;
  auto s = fmt::format("{:x}", std::bit_cast<uint64_t>(t));
  // s == "3ff1f7ced916872b"
```

godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/ehKTrMz7M

Comment: That requires c++20. Is there another option but memcpy to uint64_t in c++17?

Comment: You can implement a fallback `bit_cast` via `memcpy` as shown in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast.